# ASP MVC5 ModelState.Remove("myField") from IEnumerable<ViewModel>

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-5, modelstate

- I want to remove from model validation a required field which is
  contained in a List of viewModels.
- I need to have all fields Required for frontend validation but on backend I need to remove `company` from model validation

`modelValues` - will contain only `id` and `name`

`company` - I need to send this separate

```
$.ajax({
       ..., 
       data: JSON.stringify({"vmData" : modelValues, "company": "Google"})
       ...
});

public class UserViewModel{
    [Required]
    public int id{get;set;}
    [Required]
    public string name{get;set;}
    [Required]
    public string company{get;set;}
}

public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<UserViewModel> vmData, string company){
   if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(company)){
      ModelState.Remove("company");
   }
   
   // is never valid because "company" is always null
   if(ModelState.IsValid()){...}
}
```

Am I using wrong `ModelState.Remove("company");`? It's not working for a IEnumerable?

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve it by doing this:

```
if(!string.IsNullorEmpty(company)){
 for(var i=0; i < vmData.Count; i++){
   ModelState.Remove("vmdata[" + i + "].company");
 }
}
```